# MissingMemberHandling.Error force exception when deserializing the HTTP body

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am creating a restful web-service using .net and Newtonsoft for serialization/deserialization.

The aim is to force exceptions (preferably HTTP 400) when a required property is not included in the request.

1. Serializer configuration

   ```
   config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
           MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
           Error = delegate (object x, ErrorEventArgs error) {
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (error.ErrorContext.Error);
               throw new Exception("");
       }
   };
   ```
2. Model

   ```
   [DataContract]
   public class MyObject {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id", Required = Required.Always)]
       public string Id { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Restful end-point

   ```
   public IHttpActionResult MyAction([FromBody]MyObject request)
   ```

---

**Testing:**

When a request is fired the flow goes like this:

1. The break point of the error delegate hits ('1. Serializer configuration') and i am able to see the error log. The error is 'swallowed' and the execution is continuing in the controller.
2. The execution fails in another part of the web service.

Hence... i am able to capture the error using the delegate, but not able to propagate it (not setting a delegate at all again does not make a difference).

<strike>Isn't it fair to expect that by setting the 'MissingMemberHandling.Error', i should actually see an error in my controller?</strike>

Isn't it fair to expect that by indicating a property as 'required', i should actually see an error in my controller?

---

**Goal:**

Instead of silently failing, I would like to force an error when the HTTP body deserialzation fails.

Comment: _Isn't it fair to expect that 'MissingMemberHandling.Error' should actually throw an error?_, No. This is just an `Enum` that tells Newtonsoft how to treat missing members, in your case as an error.

Comment: @quaabaam Thank you for the answer but i was never expecting the enum to throw an error. The expectation is to actually see an error in my controller when a required member does not exist. Re-phrasing the question to avoid misinterpretation...

Comment: FYI, `MissingMemberHandling.Error` does not do what you think it does.  This setting causes an error to be thrown when a property is *present* in the JSON for which there is no corresponding member in your *class* (the member is missing).  You want the opposite, for an error to be thrown when a required property is missing from the JSON.  To do that, you need to add `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` to all required properties in your model classes.  Looks like you have that on your example `Id` property in your question though.

Comment: Oh, thank you @BrianRogers , i was not aware of that... my problem unfortunately still stands though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only legit way i could found to capture missing property errors was to check the ModelState object.

```
if (!ModeState.IsValid) {
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

This was added at the top of the controller.

---

**Update** - [FluentValidation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/) can be used to:

- Decouple the validation logic from the actual model.
- Define more complex validation rules.
- *Automatically return a BadRequest response if the validation fails* (which was the initial ask)